# nodejs socket hang up when sending request

Tags: node.js

I am trying to do the following: Send a request. The server should print the request body and then send a small response. The request's callback should print the response from the server.

Somewhere along the line I have done something wrong. I can't figure out what it is.

Server:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var reqBody = '';
  request.on('data', function (chunk) {
        reqBody += chunk;
  });

  request.on('end', function (chunk) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("<h1>Hello world!</h1>");
    console.log(reqBody);
  });
});

server.listen(8000);

console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

Request:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8000,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}
};

var reqBody = "<h1>Hello!</h1>";

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  var resBody = '';

  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    resBody += chunk;
  });

  res.on('end', function (chunk) {
    console.log('response: ' + resBody);
  });

});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write(reqBody);
req.end();
```

Edit: The error which I am getting

```
problem with request: socket hang up
```

Comment: You're missing a `}` here: `{"Content-Type": "text/plain");`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this, and updated the error, though I still get the same error.

Comment: Any command line error you getting?

Comment: I have added it (in the new edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with combining `req.write` with `GET`, which is body-less. Comment out the second-to-last line of your request and it will be fine.

Comment: Brilliant! Was trying to figure out why suddenly a very simple application was stopping. But indeed, when removing the req.write it just works again!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks like I have to do some reading about HTTP.

Comment: Happy to help. BTW if you really do need just get, it may be easier to use `http.get()` - http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback